# How do a join three tables where one table doesn't match the ID of the other two?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, aggregate

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this question with a proper SQL statement:
"How much has been sold to all customers in cities where a customer has made at least three orders. The result should display the city name and the total order quantity for these customers".

The thing is that I have three tables to work with: Order1, Order2, and Customers. The table structures for these look like this:

```
Order1 has the attributes: Ordernr, CustomerNr.
Order2 has the attributes: Ordernr, Order quantity.
Customers has the attributes: CustomerNr, Customer name, City name.
```

With this code I can join the three tables to be able to show the order quantity for each customer from each city. But how can I show the order quantity for customers in cities who've at least three orders?

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerNr, CityName, Order2.OrderQuantity
FROM Order1 INNER JOIN Order2
   ON Order1.ordernr = Order2.ordernr JOIN Customers
   ON Customers.CustomerNr = Order1.CustomerNr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.CityName, SUM(o2.OrderQuantity) OrderQuantity 
FROM Order1 o1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT o1.CustomerNr 
            FROM Order1 o1 
            GROUP BY o1.CustomerNr 
            HAVING COUNT(o1.Ordernr) >= 3
           ) AS a ON o1.CustomerNr = a.CustomerNr 
INNER JOIN Order2 o2 ON o1.Ordernr = o2.Ordernr 
INNER JOIN Customers c ON o1.CustomerNr = c.CustomerNr 
GROUP BY c.CityName
```

Comment: That seems to be a more accurate solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This query will return a list of cities with at least 3 orders:

```
select CityName
  from Customers c 
       join Order1 o1 on c.CustomerNr = o1.CustomerNr
       join Order2 o2 on o1.OrderNr = o2.OrderNr
 group by c.CityName having Sum(o2.OrderQuantity) > 3
```

Now you want all orders (I suppose from table `Order1`) from customers from these cities

```
select o1.*
  from Order1 o1 joib Customer c on c.CustomerNr = o.CustomerNr
where c.CityName in (
  select CityName
  from Customers c 
       join Order1 o1 on c.CustomerNr = o1.CustomerNr
       join Order2 o2 on o1.OrderNr = o2.OrderNr
 group by c.CityName having Sum(o2.OrderQuantity) > 3
 )
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't follow what "c", "o1" and "o2" means?

Comment: What I mean is that I only want to show the rows for the cities where customers have made at least three orders, and I want to add a column to the result (output view) named AS 'Total quantity' with their (the customers) total orders in numbers, which you get from the column 'Orderquantity' in table Order2. In other words: I want the result to be shown in two columns: City names (the cities for the customers that have made at least 3 orders) along with the column called 'Total quantity', to list the total quantity of the orders these customers have made.

Comment: The c,o1 and o2 are called 'alias'. You haven't stated what 'orderQuantity' means. I thought that this refers to the amount of orders, but it seems as if it refers to the amount ordered.